# How to split data into x_train and y_train

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to access EMNIST data from here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits

with this code:

`train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('emnist', split=['train', 'test'], shuffle_files=True)`

I tried doing this:

```
x_train = train_ds['image']
y_train = train_ds['label']
x_test = test_ds['image']
y_test = test_ds['label']
```

But I get the error
`TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object is not subscriptable`

When I try to print `train_ds` it prints

`<PrefetchDataset element_spec={'image': TensorSpec(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), 'label': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)}>`

I want to separate the image and the label into `x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test` like how you would for `mnist` data from keras.

I see from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/emnist that the structure for the feature is

```
FeaturesDict({
    'image': Image(shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=uint8),
    'label': ClassLabel(shape=(), dtype=int64, num_classes=47),
})
```

But like I'm not sure how to extract it :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to split your dataset but keep them as `tf.data.Datasets`, you could run (recommendable):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('emnist', split=['train', 'test'], shuffle_files=True)

x_train = train_ds.map(lambda i: i['image'])
y_train = train_ds.map(lambda l: l['label'])
x_test = test_ds.map(lambda x: x['image'])
y_test = test_ds.map(lambda y: y['label'])
```

You could also convert the datasets to `numpy` arrays, but it could take a while (~ 6 min on Colab):

```
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array(list(train_ds.map(lambda i: i['image'])))
y_train = np.array(list(train_ds.map(lambda l: l['label'])))
x_test = np.array(list(test_ds.map(lambda x: x['image'])))
y_test = np.array(list(test_ds.map(lambda y: y['label'])))
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for replying! I did the first code piece you gave me, and got this error: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input. in my line `model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)`

Comment: Try `model.fit(tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_train, y_train)).batch(32), epochs=20)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a good example here.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
X

list(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

X_train
y_train

X_test
y_test

train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Also, see this.

https://realpython.com/train-test-split-python-data/